# Flutter ignore certain Dependency in pubspec.yaml for web only

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, pubspec

I am trying to migrate my existing Flutter app to web. The problem is that certain packages don't exist for Web, (e.g. [ObjectBox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox)).

I don't really want to build a whole new project so is there a way to exclude certain dependencies for web? Couldn't find anything on this...

Comment: Have you found our about this? I'm trying to do the same but my search lead me here

Comment: Anybody who is looking to do the same, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387067/unable-to-build-flutter-web-and-flutter-mobile-apps-seperately) has a solution